# views project management module

Tags: views

I'm having a hard time understanding [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_reference) in the context of the Project Management modules.

I have created Project and Task Content types. For each of the Tasks I have chosen a Parent Project. I installed PM Gantt, but it does not list more than one project. I am trying to create a view to simply list all projects followed by that project's associated tasks, if any. Some projects will not have tasks.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

In Format/Settings set Grouping Field 1 to Parent.